# Couldn't retrieve all the memcache keys via telnet client

Tags: perl, memcached, telnet, libmemcache

I want to list all the keys stored in the memcached server.

I googled for the same, I got some python/php scripts that can list the same. I tested it but all went failed and none gave me full keys. I can see thousands of keys using telnet command

```
stats items
```

I used perl script that uses telnet to list keys, but that got failed too. I mean that script is listing keys but not all of them.

Do I need to reconfigure telnet ? Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 1):

memcache does not provide an api to exhaustively list all keys. "stats items" is as good as it gets to list the first 1M of keys. More info here: http://www.darkcoding.net/software/memcached-list-all-keys/

Not sure if that helps you but redis (which could be considered a superset of memcache) provides a more comprehensive API for key listing and searching. You might want to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

It you use python-memcached, and would like to export all the items in memcache server, I summerized two methods to the problem in this question: [Export all keys and values from memcached with python-memcache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730276/export-all-keys-and-values-from-memcached-with-python-memcache)