# How can one monitor memcache usage to identify outliers hogging memory?

Tags: memory, memory-management, memcached

If I'm running low on disk space, I can quickly determine the largest directories taking up the most disk space using `ncdu`. Is there a similar tool for `memcached`?

Or is the best way simply to log memcache keys and bytes used to a database to find outliers?

Comment: See if this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730276/export-all-keys-and-values-from-memcached-with-python-memcache